# Make part of image transparent with pyglet

Tags: opengl, pyglet

I have two images, "desert" image over "winter" image:

```
import pyglet


desert_img = pyglet.image.load('assets/desert.jpg')
desert = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(desert_img, x=50, y=50)

winter_img = pyglet.image.load('assets/winter.jpg')
winter = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(winter_img, x=0, y=0)

window = pyglet.window.Window()


@window.event
def on_draw():
    winter.draw()
    desert.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

Result is: [image: result]

I would like draw a square of "transparency" on desert image (winter image should be visible in this square). Is it possible ? How to do that ?

I found many question who permit to make transparency with image itself (png, alpha ... but no like i want).

Comment: Sure, that's possible :) `data = deset.get_image_data(); data = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00' + data[4:]; deset.image = data`. That replaces the first pixel with a transparent black pixel. (Each pixel is 4 bytes long, RGB and a Alpha byte. `\x00` == 0, meaning in alpha-land it's transparent.)

Comment: So the idea is to update the desert image in place where i want transparency. Nice idea ! I will work on it.

Comment: @Torxed EDIT: Forgive this comment: Image was not containing alpha channel (added with gimp) Hm, simply replace bytes by `x00` don't work in my script https://gist.github.com/buxx/8d97a4a740678d6e1dcb0f1f60410c64 (result https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/210067Capturedu20171211125015.png ) Missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Torxed suggestion, replace image content with transparent bytes where we want to make it transparent:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
import pyglet
from PIL.PngImagePlugin import PngImageFile


def replace_content_with_transparency(img: PngImageFile, x, y, width, height):
    pixels = img.load()
    for i in range(x, width):
        for j in range(y, height):
            pixels[i, j] = (0, 0, 0, 0)


desert_png = Image.open('assets/desert.png')
replace_content_with_transparency(desert_png, 32, 32, 123, 123)

fake_file = io.BytesIO()
desert_png.save(fake_file, format='PNG')

desert_img = pyglet.image.load('img.png', file=fake_file)
desert = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(desert_img, x=50, y=50)

winter_img = pyglet.image.load('assets/winter.jpg')
winter = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(winter_img, x=0, y=0)

window = pyglet.window.Window()


@window.event
def on_draw():
    winter.draw()
    desert.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

[image: image with square of transparency]